# ToolTip when you mouseover a ggplot on shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, tooltip, mouseover

I am building a shiny application.

I am plotting charts using ggplot.

When I mouseover the points on the graph, I want a tooltip showing one of the columns in the data frame (customizable tooltip)

Can you please suggest the best way forward.

Simple App:

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        h4("TEst PLot")),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot1")
    )
)
))

# server.R

library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        p <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)))
        p <- p + geom_point()
        print(p)
    })
}
)
```

When I mouse over the points, I want it to show mtcars$wt

Comment: Look into Rcharts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524227/rcharts-rnvd3-tooltip-customisation
or GooglveVis:http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

Comment: Thanks. I do use both of them. But  I want to use ggplot for plotting. And use its full flexibility. All I need is a tool tip.

Comment: animint is an R package that converts ggplot2 to SVG. Here is an example of embedding ggplot2/animint plots in shiny -- https://cpsievert.shinyapps.io/animintShiny/

To add a tooltip, you'd put `tooltip=wt` inside of `aes()`

Comment: Another option would to use the gridSVG package to convert to SVG yourself, then add a tooltip with the SVGAnnotation package.

Comment: The new shinyBS package might be very helpful for this specific need: http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html#bsTooltip. It adds additional bootstrap functionalities to shiny and tooltips are part of them.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I would love to code that answers to this question

Answer (score 20):

If I understand the question correctly, this can be achieved with the recent update of the shiny package for both the ggplot2 and the base package. Using this example from Winston Chang and Joe Cheng http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-basic.html , I was able to solve this problem. Hover is now an input argument into plotOutput() so that is added to the ui along with a verbatimTextOutput to display mtcars$wt for the point hovered over.

In the server I basically make a distance vector which calculates the distance from the mouse to any point in the plot and if this distance is less than 3 (works in this application) then it shows mtcars$wt for the closest point to your mouse. To be clear input$plot_hover returns a list of info about the location of the mouse and only the x and y elements are extracted from input$plot_hover in this example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,hover = hoverOpts(id ="plot_hover"))
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 5,
               verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()

    })

    output$hover_info <- renderPrint({
        if(!is.null(input$plot_hover)){
            hover=input$plot_hover
            dist=sqrt((hover$x-mtcars$mpg)^2+(hover$y-mtcars$disp)^2)
            cat("Weight (lb/1000)\n")
            if(min(dist) < 3)
                mtcars$wt[which.min(dist)]
        }


    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Veri Cool @Solvi. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

You can also use a little bit JQuery and conditional `renderUI` to show a custom tooltip near the pointer.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style('
     #my_tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      z-index: 100;
     }
  ')),
  tags$script('
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // id of the plot
      $("#plot1").mousemove(function(e){ 

        // ID of uiOutput
        $("#my_tooltip").show();         
        $("#my_tooltip").css({             
          top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
          left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
        });     
      });     
    });
  '),

  selectInput("var_y", "Y-Axis", choices = names(mtcars), selected = "disp"),
  plotOutput("plot1", hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover", delay = 0)),
  uiOutput("my_tooltip")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(data(), aes_string("mpg", input$var_y)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)))
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(data(), input$plot_hover)[ ,c("mpg", input$var_y)]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    verbatimTextOutput("vals")
  })

  output$vals <- renderPrint({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(data(), input$plot_hover)[ , c("mpg", input$var_y)]
    # y <- nearPoints(data(), input$plot_hover)["wt"]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    # y is a data frame and you can freely edit content of the tooltip 
    # with "paste" function 
    y
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**EDITED:**

After this post I searched internet to see whether it could be done more nicely and found [this](https://gitlab.com/snippets/16220) wonderful custom tooltip for ggplot. I believe it can hardly be done better than that.

Comment: Great find! The link in your edit is the best solution I've seen for this. One thing to keep in mind that Pawel doesn't mention is that if you scale either axis of your graph you will need to apply a similar transformation to your hover$x and/or hover$y variables before using them.

Answer (score 6):

Using `plotly`, you can just translate your `ggplot` into an interactive version of itself. Just call the function `ggplotly` on your `ggplot` object:

```
library(plotly)

data(mtcars)

shinyApp(
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( h4("Test Plot")),
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot1"))
  )
)),

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
      p <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=factor(cyl)))
      p <- p + geom_point()

      ggplotly(p)
    })
  }
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For customizations of what is shown in the tooltip, look e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've released, together with my colleague, a package called [GGTips](https://github.com/cosi1/ggtips/) (it's not on CRAN) that do just that, adding tooltips on plots. We created our own solution because we have trouble in recreating our complex plots using plotly that's not 100% compatible with ggplot2. Git repo have a link to online demo.

[image: Scatter Plot of Iris data from R]

Comment: Your library is really cool for for this purpose. When I tried it, I noticed that `renderUI` is used instead of `renderPlots` in the server function. This feature prevents me using the `hover` and `brush` features in `renderPlots`. Do you have a solution for getting the `hover` and `brush` features? (PS: I need them to extract selected datapoint for a table output)

Comment: @AliAltıntaş You can create issue on GitHub I will need to take a look, I'm not expert in R. Don't know what `hover` and `brush` do, will need to investigate.