# Tooltip with ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, shiny

I developed a Shiny app with ggplot, and for technical reasons I have to keep on using it. I am trying to create a tooltip system, as the one you can see over here with Dygraphs : http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/plotter

There is a solution suggested on SOF, but I don't like it as it's not as user-friendly as the previous one : [ToolTip when you mouseover a ggplot on shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965931/tooltip-when-you-mouseover-a-ggplot-on-shiny).
Here, there's an area under the plot in which the value is printed, and you have to click over to get the value.

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy))
a <- a + geom_line()
a
```

My question is : how to develop the same tooltip as Dygraph with ggplot ?

Thanks a bunch ;)

Comment: I want to know how to develop the tooltip system you can see with Dygraphs. I'll make it more explicit in my post.