# Identifying the points and printing a datatable with brushedPoints

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, pca, brush

I would like to use the principal component analysis for the problem that has been solved at this link [Identify points within a rectangle in a scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308600/identify-points-within-a-rectangle-in-a-scatterplot). The chart displays correctly, but I miss something in displaying the table. If anyone knew where the problem is, please help.

**Code (EDIT):**

```
head(decathlon2.active[, 1:6], 4)
##         X100m Long.jump Shot.put High.jump X400m X110m.hurdle
## SEBRLE   11.0      7.58     14.8      2.07  49.8         14.7
## CLAY     10.8      7.40     14.3      1.86  49.4         14.1
## BERNARD  11.0      7.23     14.2      1.92  48.9         15.0
## YURKOV   11.3      7.09     15.2      2.10  50.4         15.3

#################################################################

library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data(decathlon2)
    decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
    head(decathlon2.active[, 1:6], 4)
    res.pca <- PCA(decathlon2.active, graph = FALSE)
    fviz_pca_ind(res.pca)

  })

  df <- reactive({
    res.pca$ind$coord
  })

    output$plotui <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("plot1", height=300,
               brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush")
    )
  })

  output$plot_brushed_points <- renderDataTable({
      res <- brushedPoints(df(), input$plot_brush) 

    datatable(res)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("plotui"),
  dataTableOutput("plot_brushed_points")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot reproduce without that `decathlon2` data.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that in `res <- brushedPoints(df, input$plot_brush)` you reference the dataframe `df` which contains data that you generated in your `renderPlot({...})` command. That data would not be available to call in your table output command. Try adding

```
df <- reactive({
    #your data here
})
```

and then calling `res <- brushedPoints(df(), input$plot_brush)`.

If that doesn't seem to work, post some sample data and I'll update my answer.

Edit:

Here is a more explicit suggestion. You are still trying to call data from `renderPlot({...})`. Try to generate the data in the reactive statement and then call it after.

```
df <- reactive({
    data(decathlon2)
    decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
    res.pca <- PCA(decathlon2.active, graph = FALSE)
})
```

You will stil need to supply the xvar and yvar arguments to brushedPoints.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/brushedPoints.html

Comment: I corrected for your version but the problem remained the same

Comment: Can you help me, it is very important for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your data or your method of plotting, this is pretty much all I've got.

Comment: I changed as you asked, but still the same mistake, I gave the data set above

Comment: You can use the mtcars database

Comment: If you're interested in seeing this work with mtcars, I'll refer you to this link. https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html

Comment: I've seen this website, I mean first of all about using the PCA method