# Mouseover coordinates in ggplot/shiny are wrong when coord_fixed is set

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, mouseover

I am using the answer in the question "[ToolTip when you mouseover a ggplot on shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965931/tooltip-when-you-mouseover-a-ggplot-on-shiny)" to add a mouseover functionality to a ggplot object in my shiny application. In contrast to this, I need to set `coord_fixed` in ggplot for my application. Here is a minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", height = "300px", width = "100%",
             hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover")),
  verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=qsec)) + geom_point() + 
      coord_fixed(xlim=c(0,30),ylim=c(0,30))

  })

  output$hover_info <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$plot_hover))
      paste0(input$plot_hover$x, " ", input$plot_hover$y)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now my problem is that I do not get the correct x-coordinate. In the following screenshot the mouse pointer is near to the origin, but the returned x-value is around 9:

[image: Mouse pointer is near to the origin, but x-coordinate is around 9]

If I resize the browser window such that there is no space between the plot and the window border, the coordinates are correct. It seems to me that `hoverOpts` simply ignores the `coord_fixed` layout of ggplot.

Setting `width = "300px"` instead of `width = "100%"` could be a workaround. But this is not a real option for me, as I need in general a legend of variable width right to the plot, within the plot area.

How can I get the correct x-value?

Comment: I would say it is a bug. You might want to file it here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues

Comment: I don't see why your workaround won't work with legends within the plot area. I tried it out, seems to work fine.

Comment: If the plot area is quadratic and a legend is added to the right, then I get a white space at the top and the bottom (because of `coord_fixed`). And this causes a wrong y-coordinate.

Comment: I opened a issue for the problem: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1121

Comment: This bug has been fixed as of Jan 2017. The above code works as intended now. Should this question be closed?